# How to tell Jenkins to use a particular virtualenv python

Tags: python, python-2.7, jenkins, virtualenv, jenkins-plugins

I have already created a virtualenv for running my python script.

Now when I integrate this python scrip with Jenkins, I have found at the time execution Jenkins is using wrong python environment.

How I can ensure Jenkins is using the correct virtualenv?

As an example, for my case I want to use virtualenv test. How I can use this pre-prepared virtualenv to run my python script.

```
source test/bin/activate
```

Comment: curious, but if you are running jenkins on linux you may be able to affix `#!/path/to/python/virtualenv` to the start of your script.  This should tell bash which interpreter to use - you can have jenkins just call the shell script directly vs trying to execute the python.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should install one of python plugins. I've used [ShiningPanda](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ShiningPanda+Plugin). Then you'll be able to create separate virtual environment configurations in Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Python > Python installation.
In job configuration there will be Python Builder step, where you can select python environment.

Just make sure you're not starting Jenkins service from within existing python virtual environment.

Comment: As an example, for my case I want to use virtualenv test. Is there a way I can use. `source test/bin/activate`

Comment: @Baishakh Yes, this is exactly what it's doing. Add existing python virtual environment as separate configuration. Then add Build Step in the Job to start tests using that configuration.

Comment: @IvanNevostruev, Jenkins has started within the existing python virtual environment, how could I change it?

Comment: Using ShiningPanda is **not** recommended anymore, please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42650694/99834

Answer (score 9):

First, you should avoid using ShiningPanda because is broken. It will [fail if you try to run jobs in parallel](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-13236) and is also not compatible with Jenkins2 pipelines.

When builds are run in parallel (concurrent) Jenkins will append `@2`,`@3`... to the workspace directory so two executions will not share the same folder. Jenkins does clone the original worksspace so do not be surprised if it will contain a virtualenv you created in a previous build.

You need to take care of the virtualenv creation yourself but you have to be very careful about how you use it:

- workspaces folder may not be cleanup and its location could change from one build to another
- virtualenvs are knows to get broken when they are moved, and jenkins moves them.
- creating files outside workspace is a really bad CI practice, avoid the temptation to use /tmp

So your only safe option is to create an unique virtual environment folder for each build inside the workspace. You can easily do this by using the `$JOB_NUMBER` environment variable.

This will be different even if you have jobs running in parallel. Also this will not repeat.

Downsides:

- **speed**: virtualenvs are not reused between builds so they are fully recreated. If you use `--site-packages` you may speedup the creation considerably (if the heavy packets are already installed on the system)
- **space**: if the workspace is not cleaned regularly, the number of virtualenvs will grow. Workaround: have a job that cleans workspaces every week or every two weeks. This is also a good practice for spotting other errors. Some people choose to clean workspace for each execution.

### Shell snippet

```
      #/bin/bash
      set -euox pipefail

      # Get an unique venv folder to using *inside* workspace
      VENV=".venv-$BUILD_NUMBER"

      # Initialize new venv
      virtualenv "$VENV"

      # Update pip
      PS1="${PS1:-}" source "$VENV/bin/activate"

      # <YOUR CODE HERE>
```

The first line is implementing bash string mode, more details at http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/

Comment: I like this approach because it doesn't require extra plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pyenv Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pyenv+Pipeline+Plugin). The usage is very easy, just add

```
stage('my_stage'){
    steps{
        script{
            withPythonEnv('path_to_venv/bin'){
                sh("python foo.py")                              
                ...
```

You can add `pip install whatever` in your steps to update any virtual environment you are using.

By default it will look for the virtual environment in the jenkins workspace and if it does not find it, it will create a new one.

Comment: it seems it is not supported under Windows: